# Open Source Outlook and Exchange Alternative (for Calendar and Tasks)

Tags: iphone, microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange, calendar

We're using an Exchange Server and Outlook in a private context. Since Exchange is getting more and more of a monster to maintain and is basically the only thing running on a Windows VM Server, I'm looking for an alternative with the following properties:

- Server based back-end that that can be installed / deployed on my machine and is not dependent on any third party services (e.g. Google Calendar).
- (Easy) import of existing Outlook calendars, either via some feature of Exchange or by ex- and importing from Outlook.
- Roughly the basic features of the Outlook calendar (categorizations, series, etc)
- Synchronization with the iPhone over wireless without a hitch (e.g. double or missing entries)

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Scalix](http://www.scalix.com), [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com) and [Feng Office](http://www.fengoffice.com) too.

Comment: Switched to Zimbra, does everything, even contacts and tasks since iPhone OS 4.x. Thanks to the Exchange migration tool the switch even went without any complex import / export hazzle.

Answer (score 1):

search for Kerio Connect. Been running it for 18months. Does everything, Hardly put's any stress on server. Run's on XP,Mac or Linux also. Allows shared Outlook calendars on the I-Phone as Kerio integrates CALDAV with it's Exchange/MAPI style protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Why not build it all yourself using full opensource. I've done that and the only thing I need that's not open source is Bynari Connector. Uses imap to store iCal or Kolab info for calendars as well as Notes, etc.

I use Nutsmail (prettier) for webmail and hacked in my own Calendar mods and added Sieve for mail filtering (unfortnately Bynari doesn't do sieve mail filtering quite yet).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Horde Groupware](http://www.horde.org/groupware/) or running your own [Chandler Hub](http://chandlerproject.org/).